# Detect if Solution is offline using TFS and vS 2008 and C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, tfs, visual-studio-addins

I have a VS addin in C#.

I want detect if a solution is offline (about TFS) for show warning to user.

I have references like Microsoft.Teamfoundation.Client and others.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Version installed is TFS 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server's offline state is stored in a registry value named `Offline`. You should note that the online/offline state of a server is only checked for when the solution is opened.

It is stored under the registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\TeamFoundation\Servers\<tfs server name>\Offline
```

Comment: How can I get <tfs server name> of a solution sln (or csproj projects) ??